# error while sorting using multiple threads

Tags: java

I searched many stackoverflow issues on this error. Many are related to android. I could not use those answers to fix this. I'm getting this below error

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-4" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task github.MultiThreadSort$1@e70657d rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@bf3f1b0[Shutting down, pool size = 5, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6262543]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at github.MultiThreadSort.quickSort0(MultiThreadSort.java:117)
    at github.MultiThreadSort.access$0(MultiThreadSort.java:74)
    at github.MultiThreadSort$1.run(MultiThreadSort.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task github.MultiThreadSort$1@fcc7491 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@bf3f1b0[Shutting down, pool size = 5, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6262543]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at github.MultiThreadSort.quickSort0(MultiThreadSort.java:117)
    at github.MultiThreadSort.access$0(MultiThreadSort.java:74)
    at github.MultiThreadSort$1.run(MultiThreadSort.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

this is the relevant code:

```
private static final int POOL_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
private static String inputFile = "/tmp/word-sort-master/src/sowpods.txt";
private static final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(POOL_SIZE, POOL_SIZE, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS,queue);

private void quickSort0(final int l, final int r) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        String temp = null;
        if (l >= r) {
            mainLock.lock();
            try {
                count--;
                if (count == 0) {
                    overCondition.signal();
                }
            } finally {
                mainLock.unlock();
            }
            return;
        }
        i = l;
        j = r;
        temp = data.get(i);
        while (i != j) {
            while (j > i && (data.get(j).compareTo(temp) >= 0)) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                data.set(i++, data.get(j));
            }
            while (j > i && data.get(i).compareTo(temp) <= 0) {
                i++;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                data.set(j--, data.get(i));
            }
        }
        data.set(i, temp);
        mainLock.lock();
        try {
            count--;
            if (count == 0) {
                overCondition.signal();
            }
        } finally {
            mainLock.unlock();
        }
        final int s = i;
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quickSort0(l, s - 1);
            }
        });
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                quickSort0(s + 1, r);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the thrown exception, new Tasks are rejected because the executor is currently in (or has been) shutdown.

The code doesnt seem to wait until the queued tasks finished, e.g. by waiting on the Future returned by ExecutorService#submit. Although some type of Condition signalling seems to be used (not enough code shown...), the mechanism is not clear and probably faulty.